# How to set the value of a DataGridView's EditingControl

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to set the text value of a DataGridView.EditingControl. I've tried

```
myDGV.EditingControl.Text() = "1/1/2001"
```

and

```
myDGV.EditingControl.Text = "1/1/2001"
```

and

```
myDGV.EditingControl.Text("1/1/2001")
```

which causes an InvalidCastException (didn't check that could only be an integer).

There is no Value() property for the control, so how do I set the the value?

(Yes, I've verified that the cell is in edit mode)

Comment: Why not set value for the underlying business object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the [EditingControlShowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
Private Sub HandleDgvEditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles Dgv.EditingControlShowing
    If (TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) Then
        With DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
            .Text = "1/1/2001"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this event will be fired for all editable cells. If you only want to manipulate the edit control for a given column you need to add another condition. Something like this:

```
If (Me.Dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn is Me.DgvFooColumn) Then
```

---

If you need to revert the edit from the [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event then store the original value when the edit control is shown.

```
Private Sub HandleDgvEditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles Dgv.EditingControlShowing

    'Cache the edit control text
    Me.cachedEditText = e.Control.Text

End Sub

Private Sub HandleDgvCellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Dgv.CellValidating

    'Ensure that the edit control exists
    If (Not Me.Dgv.EditingControl Is Nothing) Then

        'Validate the edit
        If (Not valid) Then
            Me.Dgv.EditingControl.Text = Me.cachedEditText
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private cachedEditText As String
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work for my situation. Sorry, I didn't specify that I'm doing this in the CellValidating event, so if at all possible I need to "revert" the value there.

Comment: @marky Please see my edit. All you have to do is store the edit control value in the `EditingControlShowing` event and use that value if you need to revert.

Comment: Okay - makes sense - was wondering if a variable that both events can see would be the answer - I'll give this a shot and post here - although I'm thinking this will work...